# Mysql Error code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join, cardinality

Everything seemed to be working fine, then all of a sudden I am getting this error on my front-end:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
>   than 1 row' in /var/www/html/system/home.php:78 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/system/home.php(78): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/html/system/home.php on line 78

Under Workbench every VIEW I had created earlier is giving out this error: `Mysql Error code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row.`

Here is an example of one code that's giving the error.

```
SELECT 
    `teams`.`id` AS `id`,
    `teams`.`name` AS `team_name`,
    `teams_and_captains_view`.`captain` AS `captain`,
    IF((`teams`.`gender` = 'M'),
        'Male',
        'Female') AS `gender`,
    (SELECT 
            `categories`.`name`
        FROM
            `categories`
        WHERE
            (`categories`.`id` = `teams`.`category_id`)) AS `category`,
    `teams`.`category_id` AS `category_id`,
    `teams`.`slogan` AS `slogan`,
    `teams`.`location` AS `location`,
    `teams`.`description` AS `description`,
    `teams`.`phone` AS `phone`,
    `teams`.`email` AS `email`,
    `teams`.`tournament_id` AS `tournament_id`,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(`players`.`id`)
        FROM
            `players`
        WHERE
            (`players`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`)) AS `players`,
    `teams_and_captains_view`.`captain_id` AS `captain_id`
FROM
    (`teams`
    LEFT JOIN `teams_and_captains_view` ON ((`teams`.`id` = `teams_and_captains_view`.`id`)))
```

It seems to work when I use LIMIT, but I can't use LIMIT.

Thank you in advance

Comment: your `categories` table probably contains duplicate rows with the same `id`. try removing the duplicates and making `id` a primary key

Comment: Since you are using the sub-select to create a pseudo column, it __must__ return only one value – a column can not have more than one value in a single row. If you “can’t” use LIMIT, then you might have chosen the wrong approach to begin with. (Which one would be better suited, is hard to tell, because your question does neither include table structures, sample data and expected output, or even an explanation as to what you are actually trying to achieve here.)

Comment: I'm with FuzzyTree here. The query looks fine, so it must be the database inconsistency described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 1242 will be returned when Your subquery returns
more than one row for comparison.

Please check if you have inserted any duplicate data by mistake.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-errors.html

Comment: Thanks, one of the subqueries in 'teams_and_captains_view' was returning duplicate results. I made changes in that view and everything is now working